# How to set throttling on JMS proxy in WSO2 ESB 4.9.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

We are facing an issue with MQ JMS proxy in WSO2 ESB 4.9.0 when bulk messages are pilled up on Queue.

Back end services invoked by proxy can process only 50 requests per second and beyond that our back end services will fail.

The issue here is, when messages are pilled up on the Queue (1000messages), proxy is reading all the messages from the queue and sending to back end services & back end services are failing.

Is there any setting that we can set to on proxy to control message read by proxy service.

Here the main problem is proxy is very quick to read messages from Queue and flooding back end services. Back end services are failing because they are not designed to handle higher load

Answer (score 1):

If you need to listen to a JMS queue and want to send messages to a backend service in a controlled manner, you have to use [Message store](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/JMS+Message+Store) and [Message Processor](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Scheduled+Message+Forwarding+Processor).

Comment: Yes Asanka. I want to read messages say 10requests per second and those need to be passed to back end service .basically I am expecting jms proxy should invoke the back end service synchronoult and jms proxy should wait to read messgaes from Q until the previous message is completed

Answer (score 1):

You can define parameters in your proxy service :

```
<parameter name="transport.jms.ConcurrentConsumers">1</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.jms.MaxMessagesPerTask">1</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.jms.MaxConcurrentConsumers">1</parameter>
```

(adapt these values to your needs)

Furthermore, if you send a message to a back end service, you can choose to send it in a synchronous manner, using call mediator with blocking="true" : your proxy won't dequeue next jms message until it receive the response from your backend service. 
If, on the other hand, you use send mediator, it's asynchronous : your mediation will continue while an other thread (callback) wait for the response and therefore, your proxy will dequeue next jms message

Comment: Thanks Jean. I've tried the properties you provided but no luck.My requirement is, I want to create proxy jms listener to read 10 requests per second. I am not seeing any such properties can be set on jms proxy

Comment: In that case, consider Asanka Vithanage answer : your proxy service can store messages in a store and a sampling message processor can help you achieve your objectives.

Answer (score 0):

By setting below properties we can enable throttling or control the messages that are being sent to the backend.

[Proxy level Throttling using JMS](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI611/Tuning+the+JMS+Transport#TuningtheJMSTransport-Configuringproxy-levelthrottling)

`<parameter name="jms.proxy.throttle.enabled">true</parameter> <parameter name="jms.proxy.throttle.limitPerMinute">3</parameter>`